# Does System.out.println move the cursor to the next line after printing in some cases?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CanYouReadThis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scn.next();
        int i = 0;
        while ( input.length() > i && input.charAt(i) < 'a'  )
        {
            System.out.println(input.charAt(i));
            i++;
            while(input.length() > i && input.charAt(i)> 'Z' )
            {
                System.out.print(input.charAt(i));
                i++;
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Input : IAmACompetitiveProgrammer 
Excepted Ouput : 
I 
Am
A
Competitive
Programmer
My Output :
I
A
mA
C
ompetitiveP
rogrammer

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CanYouReadThis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scn.next();
        int i = 0;
        while ( input.length() > i && input.charAt(i) < 'a'  )
        {
            System.out.print(input.charAt(i)); // removed ln
            i++;
            while(input.length() > i && input.charAt(i)> 'Z' )
            {
                System.out.print(input.charAt(i));
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println(); // Added this line
        }
    }
}
```

I made these changes to my code and it works fine . But isn't the logic of  both programs the same. What am i missing here ? Please help me out .

Comment: `println()` always prints a line after the output.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No, the logic isn't the same. Your first program prints the "newline" character before the inner loop (which prints the lowercase characters), the second does so after it. That means your first program will have the lowercase characters at the beginning of the line and followed by the upper case characters while the second will make the line end with the lowercase characters (if there are any).

Comment: @shmosel  . Shouldn't it just print on the new line and leave the cursor there ? was this always like this in java?

Comment: "Shouldn't it just print on the new line and leave the cursor there?" - I'm not sure what you mean. A "newline" means a new line is to be started - how that's interpreted depends on the program that displays the text but normally everything that's printed after a "newline" is displayed on the next line. This means: `println('A');print('B');` might result in `A\nB` being printed which the console, file viewer or any other display program would likely interpret by displaying `A` and `B` on separate lines.

Comment: Btw, you could simplify your program by using just one loop and checking for the following conditions: Is the current character between A and Z? If so add a `println()` before printing the character unless you didn't print anything yet (maintain a separate boolean for that).

Comment: @Thomas. Thanks for the help . i understood what println does clearly now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Println renders and outputs its argument **followed by** whatever is configured as the JVM's end-of-line character sequence<sup>1</sup>.

The normal behavior and expected behavior<sup>2</sup> of a console program when it gets that sequence is to move to the start of the next line.

In the light of this, two versions of your program are clearly different.  The first version outputs a line separator after the first character, and not the last one.  The second version outputs a line separator after the last character of each word but not the first one.

The output you are getting reflects that difference.

---

> "Shouldn't it just print on the new line and leave the cursor there?"

Well, that depends on the console program's implementation.  But on platforms where `"\n"` is the line separator, the default behavior of a console program *should* be to go to the *start* of the next line.  Whether that is correct in terms of the historical meaning of the ASCII `NL` characters as implemented by 1960's era teleprinters, etc is moot.

The fact that Linux and Windows console programs interpret these things is also a historical anomaly.  But you can get yourself into problems if you hard-wire `"\n"` or `"\r\n"` into your output.  That is why `println` is provided, and why `Formatter.format` (etc) support `%n` as meaning line separator.

---

<sup>1 - On Windows it is `"\r\n"`, and on Linux it is `"\n"`.

2 - However, the actual behavior depends on the implementation of the console.  That is outside of Java's control.</sup>